# ¿Como cargar archivo .env.development en typescript?

Tags: nodejs, typescript, typeorm, environment

Que tal colegas tengo dos archivos **.env** y **.env.development** estoy usando el archivo de configuracion de ***typeorm*** y requiero de extraer las variables de **.env.development**, no tengo problema al extraer las variables del archivo **.env** pero requiero que sea especificamente de **.env.development**, estoy usando la libreria [custom-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/custom-env) para seleccionar el archivo **.env.development** pero aun asi me sigue extrayendo del archivo .env por default

orm.config.ts

```
import { ConnectionOptions } from "typeorm";
//si extrae las variables pero del archivo .env y requiero que sea del .env.development
const envfile = process.cwd() + '\\.env.development';
require('custom-env').env('development', `${process.cwd()}`)
console.log(process.env.DB_HOST)

const dbmaster = {
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    port: process.env.DB_PORT,
    username: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME,
}

const config: ConnectionOptions = {
    type: 'mssql',
    host: dbmaster.host,
    port: Number(dbmaster.port),
    username: dbmaster.username,
    password: dbmaster.password,
    database: dbmaster.database,
    entities: ['src/models/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
    options: {
      enableArithAbort: true
    },
    synchronize: true,
    migrationsRun: true,
    logging: true,
    migrations: ['src/database/migrations/**/*{.ts,.js}'],
    cli: {
      migrationsDir: 'src/database/migrations',
    }
}
export = config
```

¿Alguna idea o si tienen alguna otra libreria o metodo para mi objetivo? se los agradeceria
Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al fin pude cargar el archivo .env.development [env-cmd](https://www.npmjs.com/package/env-cmd) la solucion es simple y sencilla se añade lo siguiente en el  ***package.json***:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "typeorm": "env-cmd -f ./.env.development ts-node tsconfig-paths/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js --config src/database/orm.config.ts",
  }
}
```

Esto de acuerdo a la documentacion de ***env-cmd***
asi que mi ***orm.config.ts*** quedaria asi:

```
import { ConnectionOptions } from "typeorm";

const config: ConnectionOptions = {
    type: 'mssql',
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    port: Number(process.env.DB_PORT),
    username: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME,
    entities: ['src/models/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
    options: {
      enableArithAbort: true
    },
    synchronize: true,
    migrationsRun: true,
    logging: true,
    migrations: ['src/database/migrations/**/*{.ts,.js}'],
    cli: {
      migrationsDir: 'src/database/migrations',
    }
}
export = config
```